# Omit values from an SSRS report

Tags: if-statement, reporting-services, case

I am trying to get data for an SSRS report.  I have a query that returns multiple values for each user.

[image]

As you can see there are multiple values for RC.  If the value "R" appears in any users data I want to only show R.  If there is no "R" then the non "R" should be shown.

This is the query I am using now

```
select 
  trl.username
    , trl.EmplID
, trl.Year
, td.RC
from myDB.dbo.TRL trl
inner join myyDB.dbo.vATK atk on trl.TI = atk.TI
Inner join my2ndDB.dbo.td td on trl.TI = td.TK
```

I have tried case statements, IF/Else and I cant seem to get the results I need.  Thanks

this image probably makes more sense to what I need:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4LcW.png)

I need to limit what is shown if the the rate class is 'RACK'.  If it is rack we only want to see RACK nothing else.  if the user doesn't have a rack rate then we want to see everything.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your data looks like in each of the tables shown in your query so I had to guess what 'TRL' and 'td' look like.

I created some sample data, added 3 employees and some rows in the `TD` table so that two have an 'R' present and one does not.

```
DECLARE @trl TABLE(TI int, UserName varchar(10), EmpID int, Yr int)
DECLARE @td TABLE (TK int, RC Varchar(10))

INSERT INTO @trl VALUES 
(123, 'Dave', 1, 2023),
(456, 'Bob', 2, 2023),
(789, 'Mary', 3, 2023)

INSERT INTO @td VALUES 
(123, '4a'), (123, '2b'), (123, 'R'), (123, '3b'), (123, '3a'),
(456, '5b'), (456, '6c'), (456, '7c'), (456, '7b'),
(789, '4x'), (789, '2y'), (789, 'R'), (789, '3z')


-- and now the actual query
SELECT * 
    FROM @trl trl
    INNER JOIN @td td on trl.TI  = td.TK
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT TK FROM @td WHERE RC = 'R') r -- list on TIs where 'R' is present
        ON trl.TI = r.TK
    WHERE (RC = 'R' OR r.TK IS NULL)
```

All I did here was to left join to a distinct list of 'TK' that have an 'R' present. Based on the results of the column from this subquery we can filter the data accordingly.

So the WHERE clause reads *only return records with an 'r' unless the left join failed*

This gives us the following results. (I've left all the columns in for clarity)

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I tried obfuscate the data and obfuscated it to unreadability.  I appreciate the help.

Comment: I'm not sure if this means your issue is resolved? If this answer did solve the problem then please mark it as accepted as this helps other find similar questions that have been answered and you will also earn reputation which gives you access to more features in SO. If this didn't help, let me know and edit the question to add more info if required.